# On compile I get "error: comparison between distinct pointer types 'char*' and 'char (*)[200]' lacks a cast" on line

Tags: c++

The relevant code is

```
void setup ()
{
int respCode;
char * pResp;
const char http[] = "HTTP/1.1";
char response[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK";
    if (strstr(response,http) == &response)  {
        pResp = strchr(response," ") + 1;
        respCode = atoi(pResp);
    }
}
```

I am trying to first determine if the char array begins with "HTTP/1.1" and, if so, put the next space-delimited token (which should represent an integer) into the integer variable 'respCode'.

I get the following error:

> error: comparison between distinct pointer types 'char*' and 'char (*)[200]' lacks a cast" on line

I've searched for answers, but have not found one for this specific error, let alone the detailed explanation why it is an error.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? & is not needed

Comment: Did perchance anybody tell you recently that "in C++ an array is a pointer"? If so, don't believe him – maybe this helps.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? There's not enough code here to evaluate.

Comment: That's a lousy error message. It implies that the way to fix the problem is to add a cast rather than to compare values of the correct type.

Comment: @TriskalJM This is an MCVE :P

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to check if `http` occurs in the beginning of `response`.
`strstr (char *str1, char *str2)` returns a **pointer** to the first occurrence of `str2` in `str1`, so you should compare it to `response`, not to `&response`.

Change your condition statement to `if (strstr(response,http) == response)`.
See a working example [here](http://ideone.com/NP0AgG).

Comment: I edited the question to include a sample program with the problem.  Admittedly, there are several compile errors, most if not all dealing with char arrays, their pointers, and char array functions.  Clearly I don't understand these despite having read and tried several approaches.